# How can I save the distance between the two closest turtles as a variable for each turtles individually?

Tags: netlogo

This is my code in netlogo:

```
set distance [min-one-of turtles[distance myself]]
```

I was expecting it to calculate the distance between the turtle executing the code and the nearest turtle and then saving that to the variable 'distance' for each turtle individually but that didnt happen because the set command requires a literal value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several syntax problems here.  First, you can not use "distance" as a variable to set as it is reserved as the name of a reporter.  Second, `min-one-of turtles [distance myself]` returns the closest turtle, not the distance to it.  (Note there should be no brackets around this and there should be a space between "turtles" and the bracket.) So, say you want each turtle to identify the closest turtle and then record its distance.

```
ask turtles [    
    set closest_to_me min-one-of turtles [distance myself]
    set closest_distance distance closest_to_me
]
```

(I'm assuming that you would have two `turtles-own` variables, closest_to_me and closest_distance.)  Of course, if you only want the distance, you could combine the two commands into one.